# Attempting to split every value in a Pandas Dataframe gives an error

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a df:

```
  A                B
0 hello there      123
1 general kenobi   456
```

I want to split column A on the space so I end up with

```
  A                B
0 hello            123
1 general          456
```

df['A'] = df['A'].str.split('i')

gives back

```
  A                B
0 [hello, there]      123
1 [general, kenobi]   456
```

but when I try and get the correct index df['A'] = df['A'].str.split(' ')[0]

> I get ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: Are you splitting on i or on the whitespace?

Comment: @Ozzy08 sorry, typo is now fixed

Comment: you are missing the series str accessor: `df['A'].str.split(' ').str[0]` ?

Comment: @anky that did it :) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an extract:

```
df['A']=df['A'].str.extract('^(\w+)')
```

Output:

```
         A    B
0    hello  123
1  general  456
```

Comment: I only want to end up with 'hello' and 'general' in the A column which is why I tried accessing index 0 but got an error